# How do I handle installing scripts in Perl modules with multiple versions of Perl?

Tags: perl, installation, module

I don't think that this is a duplicate question. This is specifically about scripts that come with Perl modules.

Typically, when installing multiple Perl versions, you can have the perl executable tagged with a version number (`perl5.32`) so that they can all sit side by side in `/whatever/bin`. I need to do the same for scripts that come with modules. Example: `perltidy`. So:

Is there a setting I can throw on the config when I build perl that will automagically [sic] create 'versionated' script names?

Or, is there something I can set when I call `perl Makefile.PL` or `perl Build.PL` when I am building the script to make 'versionated' script names?

Yes, there are `plenv` and `perlbrew`, but I don't want to use those on the production side, yet there will be a period of time on my production machines when both versions will exist. I will be migrating programs over time; I will not be "big-banging" a cut over to a new version one night.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote more about this in [Make links to per-version tools](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/03/make-links-to-per-version-tools/).

I have about 30 perls installed, and I install each manually:

```
$ ./Configure -des -Dprefix=/usr/bin/perls/perl-5.x.y
$ make test install
```

Now there's something like `/usr/bin/perls/perl-5.x.y/bin/perl` and so on. If I want to install modules or scripts for that, I use that `cpan`:

```
$ /usr/bin/perls/perl-5.x.y/bin/cpan ...
```

When you install through the normal Perl toolchain, the shebang line to point to the `perl` that installed it (and see the recent Perl.com article [Bang Bang](https://www.perl.com/article/bang-bang/) for more on that):

```
#!/usr/local/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/perl
    eval 'exec /usr/local/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if $running_under_some_shell;
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
```

That sufficiently compartmentalizes the different programs from each other and each program knows which `perl` it should run.

Of course, those long paths are too much to type, so I have a program that makes symlinks in `~/bin` such that `~/bin/cpan-5.x.y` points into that. The same program takes any programs it finds in `/usr/bin/perls/perl-5.x.y/bin` and makes similar symlinks.

[rhich](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::rhich) is my own `which`-like program that takes a regex:

```
$ rhich 5.32.0 | head -4
/Users/brian/bin/perls/pod_cover5.32.0 → /usr/local/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/pod_cover
/Users/brian/bin/perls/ppodchecker5.32.0 → /usr/local/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/ppodchecker
/Users/brian/bin/perls/prove5.32.0 → /usr/local/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/prove
/Users/brian/bin/perls/plackup5.32.0 → /usr/local/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/plackup
```

Along with this, it makes links that use `-latest` instead of the version so I don't have to remember what I have:

```
$ rhich latest | head -5
/Users/brian/bin/latest_sha1.pl
/Users/brian/bin/perls/perl-latest → /usr/local/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/perl
/Users/brian/bin/perls/ptar-latest → /usr/local/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/ptar
/Users/brian/bin/perls/ttree-latest → /usr/local/perls/perl-5.30.1/bin/ttree
/Users/brian/bin/perls/dprofpp-latest → /usr/local/perls/perl-5.14.4/bin/dprofpp
```

And somewhere in there, I also just make the bare command name point to whatever is the latest, which is what I want most of the time:

```
/Users/brian/bin/perls/perl → /Users/brian/bin/perls/perl-latest
```

### perltidy

And, here's all my `perltidy` installations:

```
$ rhich perltidy
/Users/brian/bin/perls/perltidy5.30.1 → /usr/local/perls/perl-5.30.1/bin/perltidy
/Users/brian/bin/perls/perltidy5.30.0 → /usr/local/perls/perl-5.30.0/bin/perltidy
/Users/brian/bin/perls/perltidy-latest → /usr/local/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/perltidy
/Users/brian/bin/perls/perltidy5.28.0 → /usr/local/perls/perl-5.28.0/bin/perltidy
/Users/brian/bin/perls/perltidy5.26.1 → /usr/local/perls/perl-5.26.1/bin/perltidy
/Users/brian/bin/perls/perltidy5.30.2 → /usr/local/perls/perl-5.30.2/bin/perltidy
/Users/brian/bin/perls/perltidy5.32.0 → /usr/local/perls/perl-5.32.0/bin/perltidy
/Users/brian/bin/perls/perltidy → /Users/brian/bin/perls/perltidy-latest
```

Comment: After I posted this, THEN I found out about INSTALLSITEBIN, which Perl modules should be using to install their scripts. And I decided that I could add a processing step that would create "versionated" links of the scripts in /usr/local/bin. Then I read this answer and read about rhich, which should help me validate actually doing this to my manager. Don't worry, he's hardly a PHM; he's a CPAN author. :-)

Comment: Yeah, come back when you have your solution and tell us what you did.

Comment: Re "*It also shuffles around symlinks so you can "switch" to a particular version.*", No, it doesn't. It just changes the PATH in the current shell. None of which would affect scripts, because a script's installer will hardcode the path to the `perl` used to installed just as much with a perlbrew-installed `perl` as a normal `perl`. The section on `perlbrew` is bunk.

Comment: $my_last_comment =~ s/the current shell/shells loading perlbrew/

Comment: yeah, haven't looked at perlbrew in a long time so maybe I should just stfu. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update: having re-read your question, I think I mis-read it the first time. I will include my first interpretation at the end, as it may be useful.**

So as I understand it, you wish to install `/usr/bin/yourapp-1.1` and then later when people upgrade, you wish to install `/usr/bin/yourapp-1.2`?

Firstly, this seems like a badly thought out idea. If your script relies on Your::Module, then as per normal Perl module installations, Your::Module 1.2 will replace Your::Module 1.1 on the system, so if `/usr/bin/yourapp-1.1` gets run, it will be running using Your::Module 1.2. (Unless you fatpack it, I guess.)

But it certainly is possible.

Simple way is to just use File::Copy in Makefile.PL to copy the unversioned script to a new filename containing the version number, before letting MakeMaker do its thing.

---

**Earlier Answer**

If your scripts include a shebang like this:

```
#!perl
```

Then ExtUtils::MakeMaker will automatically rewrite it to point to the current version of Perl at the time the distribution is being built.

If your scripts include:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

Then it won't be rewritten, and the script will be run against whatever version of perl is found in the $PATH environment variable at runtime, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: > So as I understand it, you wish to install /usr/bin/yourapp-1.1 and then later when people upgrade, you wish to install /usr/bin/yourapp-1.2?

Not exactly. Your first answer is closer to what I need. :-)

Assume App::Mine provides the script mine.pl. If I install it under Perl 5.16 then I want the installation to yield '/usr/bin/mine5.16.pl'. If I install it under Perl 5.32 then I want the installation to yield '/usr/bin/mine5.32.pl'.

Comment: @mpersico then I would do the File::Copy thing I mentioned, but copy the script to a filename containing the *Perl* version number instead of the module version number.

Comment: tobyink - yes, of course. I see now I was not clear in the original description. I am trying to keep multiple Perl versions around. By tacking on the Perl version, as an added benefit, I CAN upgrade the module under one version of Perl while keeping it fixed under the other.

Comment: Alos understand that I am doing this to install ALL modules, not just one that I am writing. I am not so sure that your File::Copy solution applies because a) I am not opening up every module I download to modify Makefile.PL b) Not every module uses Makefile.PL; I would need to do that for every tom-dick-and-harry installation method I find. I'm sure 99.999% are Makefile.PL or Build.PL, but accommodating the tail would be a PITA.